# A compiling problem during build Substrate

Tags: rust, substrate

When I build substrate following the steps in https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup, a compiling problem appears:

```
error[E0658]: `match` is not allowed in a `const fn`
   --> /Users/adiosxia/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bs58-0.4.0/src/alphabet.rs:156:12
    |
156 |           [][match result {
    |  ____________^
157 | |             Ok(alphabet) => return alphabet,
158 | |             Err(_) => 0,
159 | |         }]
    | |_________^
    |
    = note: see issue #49146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49146> for more information
```

during compiling bs58. I try to reset the rust environment but it does not work. How to fix it?

Comment: What is your rustc version?  https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/08/27/Rust-1.46.0.html#whats-in-1460-stable

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow the tutorial you reference to without problems, I would say that it has to do with your rust versions.
`1.49.0` is working fine.
Also, I am running this toolchain as default `nightly-2020-10-06-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`